# download and convert the data of the Medical Device Adverse Event database

Tags: openfda, download

I'm trying to convert the data from this database to a format like csv or sql database. The goal is to analyze this data with R later. I would like to store them in a local database to be able to analyze all the values. How can I implement this the easiest? I have already made a few attempts but without success.

Comment: http://asdfree.com/fda-adverse-event-reporting-system-faers.html   ?

Comment: I think this question is only tangentially appropriate on this site, but feel free to contact me (contact info in profile) for free help in doing this. I suspect it's not difficult.

Answer (score -1):

Download the raw json data, convert to CSV, and put it into a postgres db.  Then you can use RODBC to analyze in R.